# Do sweet potato tops make good fertiliser tea?

Tags: fertilizer, urban-gardening, sweet-potato

I am growing sweet potato in my back yard and I come to realize the abundant amount of potato tops after harvesting, do they make a good fertiliser tea or I would just add them to the compost?

Answer (score 1):

Sweet Potatoe stems leaves, and peeling (from the roots) are excellent in solid compost and liquid compost tea or fertilizer tea. The only difference is how much water you add and whether the compost is inside of container with a a water-tight bottom and side walls.